# Kotlin - set the text below the Checkbox

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox

I couldn´t find this simple task: is there a way to change the position of the text associated with a checkbox?

In the sample below, I want the String "test" to be set below the checkbox rather than the right side. Thank you for helping a novice.

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:buttonTint="@color/white"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: Set the `android:text` of the `CheckBox` to the empty string, and put the text below it in a separate `TextView`.

Comment: Yes, I will try this solution.Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something of help maybe !

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/test"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Checkbox"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You proposed a good idea: create a separate TextView which I can place whenever I need. I will use this solution. It just is weird that there is no option in Checkbox that sets the text position automatically. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually there is an option to place the text to aside (away) from the check box using padding but I don't know think we can place it directly below the check box icon. Without using these tweaks. Enjoy !